# \cee command (from mhchem package) doesn't allow \\[10pt]

Tags: spacing, amsmath, mhchem

when using `\cee` command (from mhchem package) within align environment, `\\[10pt]` doesn't work. It works in align environment without `\cee`. Is there a workaround?

here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}

%with \cee command
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\cee{
A &-> B \\[10pt] %"[10pt]" is printed, no vertical adjustment
A &-> B 
}
\end{align}

%without \cee command
\begin{align}
A &\rightarrow B \\[10pt] %vertical adjustment works
A &\rightarrow B 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

prints:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** mhchem version 3.16 includes the fix shown below. Update will be available in a few days.

[image]

(This redefinition requires the current version of mhchem, not the one in texlive 2012)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\makeatletter
\def\mhchem@cee@i#1\\#2#3\mhchem@ENDEND{%
  \ifx\mhchem@END#2%
    \mhchem@cee@ii#1&\mhchem@END\mhchem@ENDEND%
  \else%
    \mhchem@cee@ii#1&\mhchem@END\mhchem@ENDEND%
    \g@addto@macro\mhchem@ce@out{\\}%
   \@ifnextchar[\mhchem@cee@ibrk
\mhchem@cee@i#2#3\mhchem@ENDEND%
  \fi%
}

\def\mhchem@cee@ibrk[#1]{%
 \g@addto@macro\mhchem@ce@out{[#1]}\mhchem@cee@i}
\makeatother

%with \cee command
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\cee{
A &-> B \\[10pt] %"[10pt]" is printed, no vertical adjustment
A &-> B 
}
\end{align}

%without \cee command
\begin{align}
A &\rightarrow B \\[10pt] %vertical adjustment works
A &\rightarrow B 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Yes, this is the way to go. This should be part of the package.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks, I sent a message to the package author, linking to this answer.

Comment: Thanks David! A new version of mhchem was submitted, with your solution included. So, in a few days' time, the correct answer will be: Simply use mhchem version 3.16 or higher.